# Import a Batch of Nodes via Feeds Module on Varnish environment

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, proxies

I have some problems on import node via [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

I already set feeds importer and it worked fine on the dev site and local site.

But It have some problems on the site with **varnish** already installed.

Either Batch process not working or have some response timeout or have multiple the some node import.

I really don't know how to fix that, I can't turn off the varnish because high traffic will kill my server immediately.

Does anybody have solution?

Comment: have you tried bypassing the site using pipe?

Comment: @Shabir I don't know how to do that? what's that?

Comment: Your logs should show what is happening, have you looked? Post some errors and you'll likely get more help